# How to create "et al." when using \bibliographystyle{chicago}

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I searched existing answers on how to create "et al."  but still find errors when I run the codes.

It seems that I need the `natbib` package and use `\citet{}` codes.
But I get below error message when I run `\usepackage{natbib}` codes.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \newlength{\bibhang}
```

I am using `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` to manage references. and below are all the packages that I have in my latex documents and related codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{chicago}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage[labelsep = space, bf]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\onehalfspace
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{BibTex/bib}{}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some comments about your code:

- You shouldn't load both the `chicago` package and the `natbib` package. Choose one or the other, *but not both*. Since you wish to use the `\citet` instruction, I suggest you load the `natbib` package.
- Don't load packages more than once. It not only makes for a sloppy-looking preamble, it raises the real possibility of introducing utterly unnecessary conflicts between some of the packages that are being loaded more than once, generally causing LaTeX to spew out nearly incomprehensible warning and error messages which can be difficult to interpret.
- Don't load both `color` and `xcolor`. I suggest you load just `xcolor`.
- The `hyperref` package should be loaded last.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc, 
      author  = "Anne Author and Bertha Buthor and Carla Cuthor", 
      title   = "Thoughts", 
      journal = "Circularity Today",
      year    = 2017,
      volume  = 1,
      number  = 2,
      pages   = "3-4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%% Removed duplicates from preamble...
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
%%%\usepackage{chicago} % don't load this package if you plan to use 'natbib'
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[labelsep = space, bf]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx} % no need to specify 'pdftex' option
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

% Load 'hyperref' last
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\citet{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide! I will correct my codes as you suggested.